# Plot Velocity field having three components with Quiver pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

[image]I am stuck into plotting velocity field having three components.
My data file contains velocity values on a plane `y=0`. My data is in the form.

```
x  z  u  v  w
```

where
`x` and `z` are coordinates on `y` plane
and `u`, `v` and `w` are the velocity components. Here is the data.
https://1drv.ms/t/s!Ag_e6GXfeAlsgcULSU6QvVSE4kPuGw

When I plot this using following code,

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{width=6.5cm, height=11.35cm}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \begin{axis}[ view={0}{90}, xlabel=x, ylabel=y, zlabel=z,
   xmin=-33,xmax=-20,
   colorbar style={at={(0.5,1.4)},anchor=north west}, 
   ymin=48.0,ymax=71,
   zmin=48.,zmax=71,
   colorbar horizontal,
   colorbar style={
   at={(0,1.1)},anchor=north west},
   point meta max=40, point meta min=0
   ]
     \addplot3[surf,shader=interp, faceted color=black, mesh/cols=27, 
      mesh/ordering=x varies,colormap/jet]  table {suctionM.txt};
     \addplot3 [surf,shader=interp, line width=0.2pt,-stealth,
       quiver,quiver/.cd,scale arrows=0.05, u=\thisrow{u},v=\thisrow{v}, 
       w=\thisrow{w}] table {suctiontest.txt};
   \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture} %\hspace{1cm}
     \end{document}
```

I get a vector plot, but it seems it is only plotting `u` and `v` components. (Fig. is attached)

[image: This is from Paraview, I want This is also a 2D-view]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! How could you possibly see the impact of the `w` values if you set `view={0}{90},` ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand your point. I usually use paraview to process my results. In paraview, I can actually see complete 3D vectors on the plan, though 3rd vector is shown out of the plan. With latex, I just see 2 components drawn u and v in this image but not w.

Comment: I have posted paraview image. This is what I am looking.

Comment: I do unfortunately not know what paraview is. Nor can I compile your file. The only thing I can do is to suggest to change the view to see whether or not the `w` values have an impact.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems that I have found a work around. I have exchanged v and w. Now I have u and w on the plane and v out of the plane